# bootstrap input-group not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with the input-group on my site not sizing down for xs screen sizes.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="gradient">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-s-1 col-m-2"></div><!-- /left column -->
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-s-10 col-m-8">
                <h1>IS IT ON NETFLIX?</h1>
                <p>Search to see if your TV show or movie is available to stream on Netflix</p>
                <div class="input-group searchbox">
                  <input type="text" id="searchInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button id="submit" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!
                    </button>
                  </span>
                </div><!-- /input-group -->
            </div><!-- /middle column -->
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-s-1 col-m-2"></div><!-- /right column -->
        </div><!-- /row -->
    </div><!-- /container -->
</div><!-- /gradient -->
```

The site is [isitonnetflix.net](http://isitonnetflix.net). Thanks so much!!

Comment: Loaded this up on my desktop, scaled the window down, and on my phone and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask what device and browser you were using? I've found it looks weird on iPhones in Safari and Chrome, but other devices might not be affected.

Comment: Desktop is Chrome lastest build phone Nexus 5 w/ Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Changed width on the searchbox class to 80%. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the image tag with an aligned div:

```
<div class="" align="center"></div>
```

could help with it being able to sit in the middle of the div, but you could also:

```
<img src="" align="middle" alt="">
```

you could definitely change those values and it might be kind of gross to do that, but it might help.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also facilitate bootstraps media queries in a way that `.searchbox` is defined as:

```
.searchbox {
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    /* width: 300px; */
}
```

without stating its width explicitly for **X**tra **S**mall sizes you'll see it fixes too. Another solution would be to set `max-width` instead of `width`:

.searchbox {
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    max-width: 300px;
}